# List field in model?

Tags: django, django-orm

In my model, I want a field that has a list of triplets. e.g. `[[1, 3, 4], [4, 2, 6], [8, 12, 3], [3, 3, 9]]`. Is there a field that can store this data in the database?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: look into this for mysqlDB:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836793/is-that-possible-to-store-array-in-mysql-database-using-django-model/65814823#65814823

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can convert it into string by using JSON and store it as string.

For example,

```
In [3]: json.dumps([[1, 3, 4], [4, 2, 6], [8, 12, 3], [3, 3, 9]])

Out[3]: '[[1, 3, 4], [4, 2, 6], [8, 12, 3], [3, 3, 9]]'
```

You can add a method into your class to convert it automatically for you.

```
import json


class Foobar(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def set_foo(self, x):
        self.foo = json.dumps(x)

    def get_foo(self):
        return json.loads(self.foo)
```

If you're using Django 1.9 or above, and you use postgresql, there is a new class called JSONField, you should use it instead. [Here is a link to it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField)

There is a good talk about PostgreSQL JSONs and Arrays on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGkH2yoy2MY). Watch it, it has very good information.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that we may use json serialization instead of a custom List field (like the second answer in this thread)? I'm having this concern performance-wise mainly but also I'd like to know if there is anything else that I should notice before choosing between these two approaches. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mine is simpler to implement, and you can pass a list, dict, or anything that can be converted into json.

Comment: json.dumps will make a full json conversion changing things like _None_ --> _null_. I don't get why to use that when you want a list->string conversion

Comment: You can use JSONField natively if you're running postgresql

Comment: Also, you will get null in a string

Comment: In Django 1.10 and above, there's a new `ArrayField` field you can use. See answer below.

Comment: @Ahmed I try your solution using json loads and dumps. but when i use the function "get_foo(self)" in django template, I get an JSONDecodeError.

Comment: It means you are trying to decode a value that cannot be read by JSON. What are you trying to decode?

Answer (score 54):

If you're on Django 1.10 or newer AND Postgres as your database, you can use  **ArrayField**. It's better to use than `django-taggit` or other alternatives, as it's native to the Django framework.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class ChessBoard(models.Model):
    board = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
    )
```

If you're on Django 3.1 or newer they've added support for **JSONField** with most database backends (MariaDB 10.2.7+, MySQL 5.7.8+, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite 3.9.0+). You can use this to store your Array!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield

```
from django.db import models

class ChessBoard(models.Model):
    list_of_pieces = models.JSONField()
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like its [postgres specific](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) but a great one!

Comment: How do you use this?
from django.db import models
class ChessBoard(models.Model):
    list_of_pieces = models.JSONField()
What is next? Where are your list? Do you have any field in DB or did you created a list somewhere?

Answer (score 25):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use ArrayField with a nested ArrayField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

This way, the data structure will be known to the underlying database. Also, the ORM brings special functionality for it.

Note that you will have to create a GIN index by yourself, though (see the above link, further down: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#indexing-arrayfield).

(Edit: updated links to newest Django LTS, this feature exists at least since 1.8.)

Answer (score 21):

I think it will help you.

```py
from django.db import models
import ast

class ListField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    description = "Stores a python list"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = []

        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value

        return ast.literal_eval(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value

        return unicode(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)

class ListModel(models.Model):
    test_list = ListField()
```

Example :

```py
>>> ListModel.objects.create(test_list= [[1,2,3], [2,3,4,4]])
<ListModel: ListModel object>
>>> ListModel.objects.get(id=1)
<ListModel: ListModel object>
>>> o = ListModel.objects.get(id=1)
>>> o.id
1L
>>> o.test_list
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 4]]
>>>
```

Comment: I am using python 3.5 so there are couple of issues - unicode is now str and  I am getting an error ..create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: I used this solution in django 1.7. Now i upgraded it to 1.9.12 But it is not working. What change should I made for make it workable in django 1.9.12

Comment: Please share error you are getting , also which version of python you are using ?

Comment: Consider using `json.loads` instead of `ast.literal_eval`, because the former is around 6 times faster.

Answer (score 10):

It's quite an old topic, but since it is returned when searching for "django list field" I'll share the custom django list field code I modified to work with Python 3 and Django 2. It supports the admin interface now and not uses eval (which is a huge security breach in Prashant Gaur's code).

```
from django.db import models
from typing import Iterable

class ListField(models.TextField):
    """
    A custom Django field to represent lists as comma separated strings
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.token = kwargs.pop('token', ',')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs['token'] = self.token
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def to_python(self, value):

        class SubList(list):
            def __init__(self, token, *args):
                self.token = token
                super().__init__(*args)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.token.join(self)

        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        if value is None:
            return SubList(self.token)
        return SubList(self.token, value.split(self.token))

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if not value:
            return
        assert(isinstance(value, Iterable))
        return self.token.join(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self.value_from_object(obj)
        return self.get_prep_value(value)
```

Comment: Thanks Heaps. I am using Django 1.11, and had to change member function to take 5 parameters "def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):"

Answer (score 7):

Just use a JSON field that these third-party packages provide:

- [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield)
- [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying)

In this case, you don't need to care about the field value serialization - it'll happen under-the-hood.

Answer (score 2):

With my current reputation I have no ability to comment, so I choose answer referencing comments for sample code in [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22343764/4658049) by [Prashant Gaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850358/prashant-gaur) (thanks, Gaur - this was helpful!) - his sample is for python2, since python3 has no

```
unicode
```

method.

The replacement  below for function

```
get_prep_value(self, value):
```

should work with Django running with python3 (I'll use this code soon - yet not tested).
Note, though, that I'm passing

```
encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'
```

parameters to

```
decode()
```

and

```
unicode() methods
```

. Encoding should match your Django settings.py configuration and passing

```
errors='ignore'
```

is optional (and may result in silent data loss instead of exception whith misconfigured django in rare cases).

```
import sys

...

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
            if isinstance(out_data, type(b'')):
                return value.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
        else:
            if isinstance(out_data, type(b'')):
                return unicode(value, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
        return str(value)
...
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the list and then store the values to a [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield). When you read back from the database, just group the values back into threes.

Disclaimer: according to database normalization theory, it is better not to store collections in single fields; instead you would be encouraged to store the values in those triplets in their own fields and link them via foreign keys. In the real world, though, sometimes that is too cumbersome/slow.

Comment: Note that this is deprecated as of Django 1.9 per the link in the article.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google App Engine or MongoDB as your backend, and you are using the `djangoappengine` library, there is a built in `ListField` that does exactly what you want. Further, it's easy to query the Listfield to find all objects that contain an element in the list.