# multiple values added to database when using save() method in Django

Tags: django, django-models, save, django-views

I have a model called "Section" and now I want to update one of its attribute "fifteenDaysProgressList", it's a String type. After I use the save() method, multiple values will be added to the String, but if I return the attribute before using save(), only one value will be added. So I guess the issue lays in save(). Below are my code.

```
def storeFifteenDaysData(project, developer):
thisSection = Section.objects.get(project = project, developer = developer)
thisProgress = thisSection.progress

progressList = str(thisSection.fifteenDaysProgressList)
date_progress = progressList.split()

if(len(date_progress)<15):
    date_progress.append(str(thisProgress))
else:
    for i in range(14):
        date_progress[i] = date_progress[i+1]
    date_progress[14] = str(thisProgress)
# return len(date_progress)
# update the fifteenDaysProgressList
progressStr = ""
for i in range(len(date_progress)):
    progressStr += str(date_progress[i])
    progressStr +=" "
progressStr.rstrip()
thisSection.fifteenDaysProgressList = progressStr
# return thisSection.fifteenDaysProgressList, one value added
thisSection.save()
# return thisSection.fifteenDaysProgressList, multiple values added

class Section(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True, blank = True)
percentage = models.FloatField('the percentage in the the project')
progress = models.FloatField(default = 0)
expectedProgress = models.FloatField(default = 0)
fifteenDaysProgressList = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer, null = True, blank = True)
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null = True, blank = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

For example, the original value in the attribute "fifteenDaysProgressList" is: 0.1 0.2 0.3,
now I want to add a 0.4 to the string, i.e I want to get 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4, but after I use save(), I always get 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4. I don't know why.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want one value added, or two? Can you provide an example of the values (and the values returned in each case)? If you `return` before you `.save()`, the `.save()` will not fire, since a function terminates when `return` is called.

Comment: Kevin, how are you calling this function? Have you modified the model's `save()` function at all? Can you please print the values of `date_progress` after the `date_progress[14] = str(thisProgress)` statement, and the values of `progressStr` after the `progressStr.rstrip` statement?

Answer (score 0):

As we work toward another solution, may I recommend looking into something like the following? (retrieved from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model))

```
class ListField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    description = "Stores a python list"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = []

        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value

        return ast.literal_eval(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value

        return unicode(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True, blank = True)
    percentage = models.FloatField('the percentage in the the project')
    progress = models.FloatField(default = 0)
    expectedProgress = models.FloatField(default = 0)
    fifteenDaysProgressList = ListField() # update this line with new model field.
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer, null = True, blank = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null = True, blank = True)
```

Now you can just treat your progress list like a normal Python list, which makes it easier to maintain and will be easier to keep at or below 15 elements using something like

```
thisList = thisSection.fifteenDaysProgressList
while len(thisList) > 15:
    thisList.pop(0)
```