# Django Rest Framework: Correct way to serialize ListFields

Tags: python, json, rest, django-rest-framework

Based on the DRF [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) I have a created a list of email_id stored in my model in the following way 
`Models.py`

```
class UserData(models.Model):
  emails = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
```

In my `serializers.py` file

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = serializers.ListField(child = serializers.EmailField())
```

While posting the data, the drf page shows the data in the expected format, i.e

```
"emails": [
        "bal@bal.com"
    ],
```

But, if I query the same data using python or any rest client. I get the data in the following format

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost:8000/blah/id"))
In [46]: d['emails']
Out[46]: 
[u'[',
 u'u',
 u"'",
 u'b',
 u'a',
 u'l',
 u'@',
 u'b',
 u'a',
 u'l',
 u'.',
 u'c',
 u'o',
 u'm',
 u"'",
 u']']
```

Ideally, it should have been

```
d['emails'] = ['bal@bal.com']
```

I am not sure, what exactly is wrong in here. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Your model only has one email field. It does not support storing multiple
email in the database. What you need is something like this:

```
class UserEmail(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='emails')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    # You can also store some other useful things here...
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # For example


class User(models.Model):
    ...


class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'email']


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = EmailSerializer(many=True)
```

However, this will result in a slightly different data structure:

```
[{
    'someUserField': 'foobar',
    'emails': [
        {'id': 1, 'email': 'foo@bar.maz'},
        {'id': 2, 'email': 'bill@gates.ms'},
    ]
}, {
    ...
}]
```

If you don't want this data structure, you could create a [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)

Or... if you're using `postgresql` you should be able to do this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class UserData(models.Model):
    emails = ArrayField(models.EmailField(), blank=True)
```

Comment: I thought about that. There is too much hassle in creating one to many associations. I rather have it stored as an array of email ids. One easy hack would be to append multiple emails with "," (comma) . But I am hoping for drf to give json response as array.

Comment: Well, since you're using django and a relational database, this is just the right way to do things. But, if you're using postgres you could try out the new [JSON Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField)

Comment: DRF is also very flexible and the source code clear. You can pull off all kinds of crazy stunts using custom fields. In any case a `CharField` is not the correct choice for a multiple email field. Read this: [Django List Field In Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model)

Comment: Actually `postgres` even has [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). Also, ignore the accepted answer in the link I posted. The other ones are better.