# Django Rest Framework doesn't accept ArrayField POST

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have ArrayField in my Model:

```
class ACI(models.Model):
    node_id = models.ForeignKey(Node)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    aci = ArrayField(models.FloatField())
```

Then serializers.py for this model in Django Rest Framework

```
class ACISerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    fields = (
      'id',
      'node_id',
      'timestamp',
      'aci',
    )
    model = models.ACI
```

When I manually try to input (POST) values for the model through DRF web interface, it throws error for 'aci' field: A valid number is required.
I tried to enter list for 'aci' variously, but no success:

1. 22.3, 23.4, 22.1
2. [22.3, 23.4, 22.1]
3. 22.3,23.4,22.1

Added this line in serializers.py, but still doesnt work:

```
aci = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FloatField())
```

I can't understand why DRF doesn't accept it, is it supposed just to pass it to Django itself?!

Used:

- Django = 1.8.13
- Django Rest Framework = 3.4.0
- PostgreSQL = 9.3.13

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: @Trying2Learn I get error: A valid number is required.
I can insert manually in PostgreSQL, which means everything is ok with database. DRF only accepts just one number (float), not array of floats.

Comment: Please check if this is helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624272/django-rest-framework-correct-way-to-serialize-listfields

Comment: When I enter this array: [22.3, 22.5], it throws back error like this: ['[22.3, 22.5]'] A valid number required

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue using Postman and resolved it by using the 'raw' body type instead of form-data

Answer (score 0):

Postgres Arrayfield can be tested in postman like this:
[image: arrayfield in post]

qualification is an arrayfield defined in models like this:

```
qualification = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255))
```