# Django - Model with lists in a CharField

Tags: python, django

Small dilemma here; I want to allow users to create a list of tasks (via a model form) which will be stored in the database for them to read or update each of the fields in future (so to mark a task as completed for example).
In the model I've created something like this...

```
tasks_to_do = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
```

However, I want users to be able to add as many or as few different tasks as they want. Should I do something like...

```
task_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
task_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
task_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

etc., which seems quite tedious/wasteful of code.

Or should I somehow try to store a series of strings as a list?

Apologies for the lack of code; very unsure about how to approach this problem as I haven't come across anything like this before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like the recommended way is to use a json_field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model

Comment: @nico does this only apply to integers (non-strings)?

Comment: And the rationale not to use a separate `Task` table with a foreign key is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and the most obvious solution would be to to create two separate models - one for tasks list and another for a single task.

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    # you can put here some additional information, like the name of the list, when it was created etc.

class Task(models.Model):
    todo_list = models.ForeignKey(TodoList)
    # you can put extra info about the single task (the creator, date due etc.)
```

So everytime you want to add a new task to your list, you create another `Task object` with `todo_list` field's value set to `TodoList object`.

Or you can add it another way, using reverse relationship as described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/)