# Save dates/time in a list in model Django

Tags: python, django

I want to save some dates as a list in a Django model and can't get it done properly. So first I tried `last_visits = CharField(....)` and wrote a function to add values to that Charfield. This did not work since I couldn't make a proper list.I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model)(JSONField model attribute for lists), but storing python time into JSON will make problems since Json can't serialize it properly and converting it to `str` would cause new problems since I would have to convert it back later.

So my question is: Is there an easy way to save multiple dates(list/array)?

```
someList = list()
global someList
def logins(self):
    someList.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    return someList
```

Thats a function I wrote and it works fine but the values are not getting saved. How would I add the old values of the list and add a new one into a model attribute (Charfield/textField/JSONField)?

I tried it like the following:

```
#"last_visit" is the model attribute
someList.append(self.last_visit)
self.last_visit += json.dumps(datetime.datetime.now())
self.last_visit = someList
self.last_visit.append(datetime.datetime.now())
self.last_visit.save()
```

but none of these worked. Please note that I didn't used all of these at once I just wanted to give an overview of what I tried.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that storing a list of date as char or text field is a good solution. Why don't you use model relations? I show you an example of model with an Event object that includes multiple related dates. Using a DateField is also convenient for filtering!!

```
class Event(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)


class EventData(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: In `EventData`, did you mean `ForeignKey(Event, ...`?

Comment: thanks for the answer but I really don't know what im supposed to do with it. Feels a bit copy pasted from some code but not configured in any way for my needs and yes, I know what a ForeignKey is.
"I don't think that storing a list of date as char or text field is a good solution" thats why I asked the question...