# Django Models make a field that is updating when another field is changing

Tags: django

I want to make a TextField in my model that store every changes of another field. That field to store data like an array. How can I do that? Can anybody give an advice?

exemple:

```
class Exemple(models.Model):
  field = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, blank=True)
  history_field = models.TextField(blank=True)  # => ['old_field_value', 'field_value']
```

When "field" receive a value I want to append that value to "history_field"

> ## SOLUTION**

pip install django-mysql

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_mysql.models import ListTextField

class Exemple(models.Model):
 field = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, blank=True)
 history_field = ListTextField(
                   base_field=models.TextField(),
                   size=150,
                   blank=True
                   )

@receiver(post_save, sender=Exemple)
def update_history_field(sender, instance, **kwargs):
 if instance.field:
  data = Exemple.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
  history = data.history_field
  history.append(instance.field.name) #field is foreignkey
  Exemple.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).update(history_field=history)

#result history_field=['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

This is the solution that I`ve made

Comment: I believe your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model

Comment: You should use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/) for this. Bind a `pre_save` event to your model, and if the "field" changes, append to "history_field".

Comment: I`ve made a pre_save but when I want to get the  current array from history_field and add another element to that array he told me that is a 'str' not array

Comment: You need to handle the data type yourself. There is no "ListField" in django, so if you want to store a `list` inside a `TextField` you need to implement that yourself.