# Is that possible to store array in mysql database using django model?

Tags: mysql, django

i have a array of values and want to store in **mysql** database using **django** model.py. what are the possible ways that i can store array values

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **django_mysql** we can store list into the database. For this you have to install django_mysql

```
pip install django_mysql
```

Then we can use **ListCharField** of django_mysql, and can define the basic attributes line base_field, size, max_lenght and etc.

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Model
from django_mysql.models import ListCharField

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    post_nominals = ListCharField(
        base_field=CharField(max_length=10),
        size=6,
        max_length=(6 * 11)  # 6 * 10 character nominals, plus commas
    )
```

You can simply insert the data like that:

```
p = Person.objects.create(name='Horatio', post_nominals=['PhD', 'Esq.'])
```

For the reference follow the link: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use ArrayFields as below

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
arr_data= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank = True), size = 8)
```

Comment: Oh!, My bad. I gave the answer directly for postgres. Instead of saying not supported for MySql and then sharing the answer for postgres.

Answer (score -1):

> Mysql does not support arrayfield.
>
> You can use postgresql