# List Field in Django for responsing through views.py

Tags: python, django

In my django project, I have a code that returns a list of lists like this:

```
[["2019-01-04", "0:00:00", 0.0], ["2019-01-04", "0:30:00", 0.0]]
```

I want to store this list into my database, but it seems that there is nothing called ListField in django models. I also tried to change the list into String and save it in CharField, but since the list contained quotation mark inside, django would format it into something like this

```
[[\"2019-01-04\", \"0:00:00\", 0.0], [\"2019-01-04\", \"0:30:00\", 0.0]]
```

Could anyone please suggest a way to overcome this. Thanks.

Comment: Postgresql in django has ArrayField. what is your DMBS?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model maybe this is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you use foreign keys. Documentation available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). This allows you to store an array of things but you don't need to install Postgres -- which is a pain for me and you **cannot** store objects, only strings or numbers.

```py
# models.py

class TimeObject(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(...)
    dt = models.DateTimeField(...)
    whatever = models.IntegerField(...)

class AllStuffs(models.Model):
    timeobjs = models.ForeignKey(TimeObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Using things built-in to Django, you can achieve the problem you have now and you can have total control over your models.

Comment: Hi Crimsonpython24, thank you for your response. I'm not sure if this one can solve my problem, since I need to store a whole **list of lists** as a single attribute in my database.  If I'm right, your solution can just store a list on a row, instead of list of lists. Besides that, I'm using MySQL, will this solution be correct. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, because every item inside your list is a list. The alternative above that I suggested is to replace each child list with an object, like `[<TimeObject1>, <TimeObject2>, ...]`. ForeignKey and models should work across all databases as it's provided by Django.