# How I can save a list of string in my model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, backend

I want to store a list of strings as a field of my model.

```
categories=['Abstract Strategy', 'Medieval']
```

I want to save the category as a field.
my database is sqlite3.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340258/django-list-field-in-model

Answer (score 0):

on your Django model, you need to use a CharField with the `choices` parameter. And your choices need to be in this Tuple format, where the first part of each tuple is the system name that goes in the DB, and the 2nd part is what shows nicely on Forms.

```
categories = (
    ('abstract_strategy', 'Abstract Strategy'),
    ('medieval', 'Medieval')
)
my_field_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, choices=categories)
```